# How to improve ILIKE Performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

My application has a page where all the cities of a state that start with a particular alphabet are shown.

For ex:

```
State: Alabama, Page A
--> All cities in Alabama starting with alphabet 'A'
```

This is my query

```
City.where(state: 'Alabama').where("name ilike?", "a%")
```

This query takes ~110 - 140 ms. Is there any way in which I can bring down the query time to <10 ms.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you know about [`Database_index`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) and a [`Postgresql feature explain`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/using-explain.html)?

Comment: @Зелёный Cities table has a database index on 'name' column. I am not familiar with 'PostgreSQL explain'

Comment: well then you should look it up. Link is in @Зелёный 's comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't use usual index for LIKE operator

```
postgres=# create index on obce(nazev);
CREATE INDEX
Time: 120.605 ms
postgres=# explain analyze select * from obce where nazev like 'P%';
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                             QUERY     PLAN                                              │
╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ Seq Scan on obce  (cost=0.00..137.12 rows=435 width=41) (actual time=0.023..2.345 rows=450 loops=1) │
│   Filter: ((nazev)::text ~~ 'P%'::text)                                                             │
│   Rows Removed by Filter: 5800                                                                      │
│ Planning time: 0.485 ms                                                                             │
│ Execution time: 2.413 ms                                                                            │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(5 rows)
```

You should to use special syntax with `varchar_pattern_ops` keyword

```
postgres=# create index on obce(nazev varchar_pattern_ops);
CREATE INDEX
Time: 124.709 ms
postgres=# explain analyze select * from obce where nazev like 'P%';
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                          │
╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ Bitmap Heap Scan on obce  (cost=12.39..76.39 rows=435 width=41) (actual time=0.291..0.714 rows=450 loops=1)                 │
│   Filter: ((nazev)::text ~~ 'P%'::text)                                                                                     │
│   Heap Blocks: exact=58                                                                                                     │
│   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on obce_nazev_idx1  (cost=0.00..12.28 rows=400 width=0) (actual time=0.253..0.253 rows=450 loops=1) │
│         Index Cond: (((nazev)::text ~>=~ 'P'::text) AND ((nazev)::text ~<~ 'Q'::text))                                      │
│ Planning time: 0.953 ms                                                                                                     │
│ Execution time: 0.831 ms                                                                                                    │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(7 rows)
```

But this doesn't work for ILIKE - the workaround can be functional index:

```
create index on obce(upper(nazev) varchar_pattern_ops);
select * from obce where upper(nazev) like upper('P%');
```

Note: "Nazev" is the name in Czech language

Another possibility is using [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) extension and using trigram index. It is working for both `LIKE`, `ILIKE`, but the index is much bigger - it is not problem for relative small static tables.

```
create extension pg_trgm ;
create index on obce using gin (nazev gin_trgm_ops);

postgres=# explain analyze select * from obce where nazev like 'P%';
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                          │
╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ Bitmap Heap Scan on obce  (cost=15.37..79.81 rows=435 width=41) (actual time=0.327..0.933 rows=450 loops=1)                 │
│   Recheck Cond: ((nazev)::text ~~ 'P%'::text)                                                                               │
│   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 134                                                                                        │
│   Heap Blocks: exact=58                                                                                                     │
│   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on obce_nazev_idx1  (cost=0.00..15.26 rows=435 width=0) (actual time=0.287..0.287 rows=584 loops=1) │
│         Index Cond: ((nazev)::text ~~ 'P%'::text)                                                                           │
│ Planning time: 0.359 ms                                                                                                     │
│ Execution time: 1.056 ms                                                                                                    │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘    
(8 rows)
```